# When I try to execute 'npx create-next-app', the installation never ends

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, next.js

I'm trying to create a new NextJS app, but the command `npx create-next-app <name>` never ends. It installs a few files along the way (including `node_modules/`), then after a while, among all the great lines that a CMD shows, it displays an installation line that never ends. When I try to cancel the installation, I must restart my PC completely.

Note: the last line is always beginning with "reify:something: timing ... Completed in Xms"

[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Mvm.png)

I've tried to reinstall NodeJS, It did not change a single thing.
I've tried to delete the cache, nothing changed.

I have used npm in the past and it always worked fine, I have absolutely no idea why it doesn't work now.

Please help me, I don't know what to do, except to throw my PC out the window.

I'm on Windows 10, using npm 7.24.1 with node v14.17.6

Comment: While I don't know what is causing this, I have experienced similiar issues myself fairly often when using Windows. I'd recommend you to try out WSL, I have had much less issues since integrating it into my development workflow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Comment: How long did it take? Also in the screenshot you linked, did you exit the process?

Comment: I exit the program with ^C but I cannot close the CMD. It takes around 20 seconds to get there. Note: I exit the program only because the installation is taking forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I fixed my problem thanks to Marcel Herd: I installed WSL 2 and from now on I'll use Ubuntu on Windows to execute npm commands.

However, I have still no idea why I had to do such a thing...

Thank you

If you are interested, here are links that helped me:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment
- https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl